# How to get the total amount sent to an Etherum address

Tags: api, rpc, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm a noob at Ethereum and need to make statistics from blockchain data.

I have a full node up and running with RPC ready, but can't find a clue in the doc on how to query :

1. Total number of transactions in/out for a contract/address
2. Total number of ether sent/received for a contract/address

The only solution I found was to parse all blocks and transactions in a double for loop and the performance is way too slow to do this.

Can someone help me ?

**TL;DR : How do you do getTotalAmountSentTo(address) and getTotalNumberOfTransactionsFor(address) in Ethereum?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web3JS you can use [web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) function to find all the transactions you are interested in.